# Why can't Mathematica integrate this PDF?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, distributions

I'm trying to integrate a transformed Gumbel PDF in *Mathematica*.

```
Integrate[E^(η*(-(x - q)) - E^((-η)*(x - q))), {x, t, ∞}]
```

However, it doesn't compute. It's fine when I do the standard Gumbel.

```
Integrate[E^(-E^(-x) - x), {x, t, Infinity}]
```

which gives me $$1-e^{-e^{-t}}.$$

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think because of your parameters it's having a hard time inferring convergence / continuity conditions.

For instance, the integral diverges when $\eta < 0$.

You can specify assumptions and get the result:

```
Integrate[E^(-η(x - q) - E^(-η(x - q))), {x, t, ∞}, Assumptions -> η > 0]
```

> ```
> (1 - E^-E^((q - t)η))/η
> ```

Side note, *Mathematica* has no problem computing the indefinite integral without specifying any assumptions:

```
Integrate[E^(-η(x - q) - E^(-η(x - q))), x]
```

> ```
> E^-E^(q η - x η)/η
> ```

See [this blog post](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/01/19/mathematica-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/) explaining why definite integrals are much harder than indefinite ones.

Answer (score 2):

It should be mentioned at this juncture that `ExtremeValueDistribution[]` is built-in; up to a normalizing factor, your distribution is equivalent to `ExtremeValueDistribution[q, 1/η]`. Thus,

```
PDF[ExtremeValueDistribution[q, 1/η], x] // Simplify
   E^(-E^((q - x) η) + (q - x) η) η

SurvivalFunction[ExtremeValueDistribution[q, 1/η], t] // Simplify
   1 - E^-E^((q - t) η)
```

The assumptions mentioned by Chip are already taken into account in this case:

```
DistributionParameterAssumptions[ExtremeValueDistribution[q, 1/η]] // Simplify
   q ∈ Reals && η > 0
```

---

N.B. for some reason, what *Mathematica* calls `GumbelDistribution[]` is the one corresponding to the asymptotic distribution of the minimum value, while `ExtremeValueDistribution[]` refers to the maximum value version.