# Mathematica Integration Problem

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am new user of *Mathematica*. Can anybody help me to solve this integration? I really needs your help.

```
Integrate[(1 - (1/(1 + A x^(-ao)))) x, {x, 0, r}]
```

Can not give any solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps this?  Assuming[ao>0, Integrate[(1-(1/(1+A x^(-ao)))) x, {x,0,r}]]  which is giving Mathematica a hint about the domain of ao. You can also try giving it hints about the domain of r. Otherwise Mathematica assumes none of the things you might be taking for granted when thinking about the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since there are three constants and all of them are crucial in the computation we should somehow restrict possible values of the constants.  One can see that the integral is quite different in three distinct cases `b < 0`, `b == 0` and `b > 0`:

```
TraditionalForm[ 
  int[A_, b_, r_] = 
    Piecewise[{Integrate[(1 - (1/(1 + A x^(-b)))) x, {x, 0, r},
                         Assumptions -> # && r > 0 && A ∈ Reals], #} & /@
               {b < 0, b == 0, b > 0}]]
```

[image]

One has to remember that the above expression is true under the following assumptions `b ∈ Reals && r > 0 && A ∈ Reals`.

In general `ConditionalExpression` can be simplified with more restricted assumptions, e.g.

```
FullSimplify[ int[A, b, r], b == 2 && A == -4 && r <= 2]
```

> ```
> -2 Log[1 - r^2/4]
> ```

but sometimes it simplifies automatically, e.g.:

```
int[1, 1, r]
```

> ```
> r - Log[1 + r]
> ```

On the other hand as a function of `b` and `r` (it simply depends on `A`, so let `A == 1`, for `A < 0` we should consider another case):

```
Integrate[(1 - (1/(1 + A x^(-b)))) x, {x, 0, r}, 
           Assumptions -> b > 0 && r > 0 && A == 1]
```

> ```
> 1/2 r^2 Hypergeometric2F1[1, 2/b, (2 + b)/b, -r^b]
> ```

```
Plot3D[ 1/2 r^2 Hypergeometric2F1[1, 2/b, (2 + b)/b, -r^b], 
        {b, 0, 5}, {r, 0, 5}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to calculate the corresponding indefinite integral first and then plug in the bound:

```
int[x_] = Integrate[(1 - (1/(1 + A x^(-ao)))) x, x];
int[r] - int[0] // FullSimplify
```

> ```
> 1/2 r^2 Hypergeometric2F1[1, 2/ao, (2 + ao)/ao, -(r^ao/A)]
> ```

Comment: One does have to be careful with this technique, though;  see [this blog post](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/01/19/mathematica-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/) (linked in [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113024/why-cant-mathematica-integrate-this-pdf).)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment that assuming the exponent `a0>0` will help to speed things up and will avoid the complex part.

I tried to evaluate the integral in both mathematmica and maple,

```
 Integrate[(1 - (1/(1 + A x^(-ao)))) x, {x, 0, r}]
```

The output turn out be unevaluated integral but as suggested by @Bill, if assume `a0>0` then we have an answer

```
1/2 r^2 Hypergeometric2F1[1, 2/ao, (2 + ao)/ao, -(r^ao/A)]
```

In maple without assuming anything and evaluating the indefinite integral, I get an answer

```
1/2*x^2-1/2*x^2*hypergeom([1, -2/a0],[1-2/a0],A*x^(-a0)*(-1)^(1/2*csgn(A*I)+1/2*csgn(x^(-a0)*I)-1/2*csgn(x^(-a0)*I)*csgn(A*I))*I)
```